# Database Design - Name for this convention?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I am trying to figure out a good way to handle the following scenario in Entity Framework, but do not know the name for the convention used, so I'm having a difficult time finding results:

**The Base Tables**

Category Table: CategoryID, Name, ..., Active

Webpage Table: WebpageID, Name, ..., Active

Product Table: ProductID, Name, ..., Active

Link Table: LinkID, Name, ..., Active

**The Relation Table**

Relationships Table: ID, CategoryID, ChildID, ChildTypeID, SortOrder

(ChildID can be CategoryID, WebpageID, ProductID, or LinkID. ChildTypeID identifies which table/type the ChildID is linked too)

What should I be using for search terms to find information on this type of relationship? Does anyone have any links to resources that might be useful in handling this sort of thing in Entity Framework? I'm contemplating breaking the Relationships table out into four tables, but would like to make sure I'm not creating more work for myself than is necessary.

Comment: Thats a very poor structure. You should have a separate relationship table for each type of relationship so that you can enforce foreign key constraints. This structure is harder to query and much more likely to contain bad data.

Comment: HLGEM, hence my comment about contemplating breaking the relationships table into four tables. Poor structure is in the eye of the beholder... Sometimes you have to normalize, denormalize, and do some things out of the ordinary to fit your specific needs. In this case, a requirement was to return a paged and sorted list of all of a category's contents. The SortOrder column is not specific to the ChildType, but is across all types within the category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Hibernate it would be called Inheritance Mapping. Try searching Entity Framework documentation for similar terms.